# ServiceStack Service startup error

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using the below code but I am getting error on this line `appHost.Start(listeningOn)`.

I deleted bin and obj folders, and  even restarted Visual Studio, but the error persists:

Here is the code:

```
var listeningOn = $"http://*:{Globals.RestServicePort}/";
var appHost = new AppHost();
appHost.Init();
appHost.Start(listeningOn);
```

and this is the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

StackTrace:

`at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.Start(String urlBase, WaitCallback listenCallback)
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.Start(String urlBase)
at NotifierServer.WindowsService.NotificationService.Start() in E:\dev\projectname\WindowsService\mService.cs:line 23`

AppHost Class:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost()
        : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(NotifierRestService).Assembly)
    {
        ////disable metadata
        //SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        //{
        //    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Metadata)
        //});
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IResourceManager>(new ConfigurationResourceManager());

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
            }));

        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

        // use redis cache server
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
        container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());

        // for authentication
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(Globals.ConnectionStringNotifier,
            ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

        var userRep = new OrmLiteAuthRepository(dbFactory);
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

        // create necessary auth tables
        userRep.CreateMissingTables();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a process that hung and has not gone away. Try finding it in Task Manager and/or rebooting your system.

Comment: I have removed every process related to Visual Studio as well as my service but still the error is there, restarting machine is not an option right now as this is server machine.

Comment: Then it must be a process not related to VS. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the full StackTrace with the Exception, the generic ServiceStack Startup code provided is inconsequential to the Error you're receiving.

The Exception is indicating you're trying to access a file that is used by another process. You first need to identify what file has the issue, then you can use [Process Explorer to find out which process is locking it](https://superuser.com/a/117908).

Also running on a low port number requires Admin permissions which you can avoid by choosing a port number >2000.

Comment: StackTrace added I've also added the AppHost class implementation.

Comment: @Ali have you tried going to the url to see if something's already running? Does changing the port work?

Comment: Yes currently I am checking processes in process explorer and changing port i.e. 1338 still throwing the same error.

Comment: @Ali I meant going to `http://localhost:1338` in a browser to see if something's already running, otherwise try changing the port number to a number > 2000.

Comment: Going to `http://localhost:1338` showed `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error, but setting the port to > 2000 worked!, but I didn't understand is there any file created by the service which has open handle somehow? I am going to accept this answer though.

Comment: @Ali ok not sure about the error message, but running on a low port requires Admin permissions which is likely the related to your issue.